# How to automaticallly accept when adding a repository?

Tags: shell-script, input

Code :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install systemback -y
```

after entering the first command it will show something like this:

> Simple system backup and restore application with extra features
>
> Systemback makes it easy to create backups of the system and the users configuration files. In case of problems you can easily restore the previous state of the system. There are extra features like system copying, system installation and Live system creation.
>
> This PPA contain the stable version of Systemback.
>
> Currently supported Ubuntu releases:
>
> - 14.04.X LTS
> - 15.04
> - 15.10
>
> More info: [https://launchpad.net/~nemh/+archive/ubuntu/systemback](https://launchpad.net/%7Enemh/+archive/ubuntu/systemback)
>
> Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

And I'm creating a script to install automatically, so how to automatically continue?

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your question to improve the formatting and to allow for answers other than pressing Enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `--yes` option. As described in [the manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html):

> -y, --yes: Assume yes to all queries